# Prometheus custom collector just hangs when exporting

Tags: python, prometheus

I am trying to create a custom collector that collects a routers memory stats and export to prometheus, I am using the python prometheus-client, and have the following code:

```
from prometheus_client import start_http_server
from prometheus_client.core import CounterMetricFamily, REGISTRY
import requests
import json



class MemoryCollector(object):
    def collect(self):
        c = CounterMetricFamily('ODL_memory_monitoring', 'Memory for each process on box', labels=['node', 'process'])
        url = "http://<ip>:8181/restconf/operational/network-topology:network-topology/topology/topology-netconf/node/IDC_R-Leaf3/yang-ext:mount/Cisco-IOS-XR-procmem-oper:processes-memory/no\
des"
        headers = {
                'authorization': "<token>",
                'cache-control': "no-cache",
                'postman-token': "<token>"
        }
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
        reply = json.loads(response.text)
        for node in reply['nodes']['node']:
            for process in node['process-ids']['process-id']:
                if process['name'] == 'tcp':
                    c.add_metric([node['node-name'], process['name']], process['malloc-size'])
                    print("Adding metric {} {}".format(node['node-name'], process['name']))
        yield c



def main():
    start_http_server(8000)
    REGISTRY.register(MemoryCollector())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I navigate to the webpage (`<ip>`:8000), it just hangs and doesn't get updated with the metrics.  Is there any performance issues?  Is this the correct way of creating a custom collector?

Answer (score 0):

You've an infinite loop, try removing the `while True:`.

Comment: So REGISTRY.register(MemoryCollector()) will loop over and over again with the collect method?

Comment: It's called on every exposition request.

Comment: I removed the while true statement, but it still seems to hang when I go to the web page, is there a way to optimize it?  I am only doing one metric now (tcp memory) but I would later want all (over 75 metrics) to be exported.  What is an exposition request, and how do I set it to loop continously so it always monitors the memory?

Comment: It's probably the http request you're making taking too long, try adding a timeout. What you're doing is expensive Prometheus-wise, though you should outdent that yield. You only need to yield the MetricFamily once.